# Should i create a datasource for the database or for each table

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, wpfdatagrid

I have a database with 8 tables. Each of these table is displayed as a datagrid in one application to maintain.

I created a single data source for the database and started wondering if it affects the performance when i save or delete an entry from one table that is linked to a datasource with multiple tables.

Will it be better if i create an individual datasource for all my tables ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There would be no value in creating multiple datasources. Datasources are designed to contain tables which contain rows. When you update a table in a datasource, the changes go "right to" that table without any (significant) performance hits. Significant in this context means it might be an additional reference of a pointer or something tiny. Compared to the overhead of going to the database it will be nothing.